# Customize Bar-series and BarCategoryAxis in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2, qtcharts

I need to customize the `BarCategoryAxis` labels and `BarSeries`. Following is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtCharts 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ChartView {
        id: chartview
        width: parent.width
        height: 300

        BarSeries {
            name: "BarSeries"
            axisX: BarCategoryAxis {
                id:barAxis
                property int minCategory: 10
                property int maxCategory: 100
                property int category: 50
                categories: ["10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100"]


                min:  Math.floor(((minCategory + sb.position *
                                   (maxCategory - minCategory - category)) + 9)/10)*10

                max: Math.floor((((minCategory + sb.position *
                                   (maxCategory - minCategory - category)) + category) + 9)/10) *10
            }

            axisY: ValueAxis {
                id:axisY
                min: 0
                max: 70
                tickCount: 5
                labelFormat: "%.0f"
            }

            BarSet { values: [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7] }
            BarSet { values: [5, 1, 2, 4, 1, 7] }
            BarSet { values: [3, 5, 8, 13, 5, 8] }
        }

    }

    Slider {
        id: sb
        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        height: 30
    }
}
```

1) How to align the `X Axis` labels exactly below the grid? currently, it is at center as below:

[image]

I Tried with `ValueAxis` but it will not plot the bars properly but labels will be exactly below the grid.

2) Currently, `slider` moves the graph but not fluent. Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

1) Did you try with [**CategoryAxis**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-categoryaxis.html) instead of **BarCategoryAxis**, it has an attribute [labelsPosition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-categoryaxis.html#labelsPosition-prop).

2) First you should make your computation inside the Slider slot :

```
Slider {
    onPositionChanged: {
         barAxis.min = ...
         barAxis.max = ...
    }
}
```

Then I suggest to use **ChartView** functions like [scrollRight(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#scrollRight-method), it's much more smooth.

Comment: `CategoryAxis` will not suit my requirement since the graphs should work for real-time and it's difficult to find the end value of previous when giving the category range and it's clearly mentioned in QT docs that `endValue specifies the high-end limit of the category. It has to be greater than the high-end limit of the previous category. Otherwise, the method returns without adding a new category`. and Regarding scroll, I will try to use `scrollLeft` and `scrollRight` thanks for the suggestion